# stop re rendering after promise is fulfilled

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, es6-promise

This is a simple app in react that fetch the data from the nasa api.Div tag is re rendering continuously (like infinite loop) is there be any method to stop the api fetching after a promise is fulfilled.Also my arr is changing its value. . Thanks in advance.

```
 function App() {
      const [arr, setarr] = useState([]);
      var promise = new Promise(async(resolve, reject) => {
        axios
          .get(
            "https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=R4s5xcOxoYklREakJOSoeNMCOK4tpM8iqg6slJ15&count=2&hd=true"
          )
          .then((res) => {
            //res.data[i].hdurl
            resolve(res.data);
          });
        return promise;
      });
    
      let show = () => {
        promise.then((result) => {
          setarr(result);
        });
      };
      //show();
    
      return (
        <>
           <div className="container">
            {arr.map((val, i) => {
              return (
                <div
                  id="carouselExampleIndicators"
                  className="carousel slide"
                  data-bs-ride="carousel"
                >
                  <div className="carousel-indicators"></div>
                  <div className="carousel-inner">
                    <div className="carousel-item active">
                      <img
                        src={val.hdurl}
                        key={i}
                        className="d-block w-100"
                        alt="img"
                      ></img>
                      <br />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              );
            })}
          </div>
        </>
      );
    }
    
    export default App;
```

Comment: Couple of problems in your code: 1. Move the code that makes the request inside the `useEffect` hook: `useEffect(() => { /* your code here*/}, [])` 2. Don't use the promise constructor - `axios.get` already returns a promise;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put API requests under useEffect hook. The empty dependency array at the end means that the hook will only trigger once when the component is first rendered. Here's the code:

```js
import { useEffect } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [arr, setArr] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(
        "https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=R4s5xcOxoYklREakJOSoeNMCOK4tpM8iqg6slJ15&count=2&hd=true"
      )
      .then((res) => {
        setArr(res.data);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="container">
        {arr.map((val, index) => {
          return (
            <div
              id="carouselExampleIndicators"
              className="carousel slide"
              data-bs-ride="carousel"
              key={index}
            >
              <div className="carousel-indicators"></div>
              <div className="carousel-inner">
                <div className="carousel-item active">
                  <img
                    src={val.hdurl}
                    className="d-block w-100"
                    alt="img"
                  ></img>
                  <br />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```